# Which Drupal gallery module can do this?

Tags: drupal

I would like to make something like this in Drupal:

At first I chose a gallery that contains a set of images.

[image]

And after a click on one of these galllerie I get something like this:

[image]

The pager is important to have like this. I know there are a few galleries with more effects but I need a simple pager like this with all images represented as one number and next and previous link too.

Thanks in advance for any advice which gallery/image module is capable of something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this simply with the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

For more information on using Views, see its [documentation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/views)

If you want the images to automatically rotate, you can also use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/)? It has a [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_galleria) for Drupal 6 if you need Views integration.